# How to Select an Array By Selected List Position in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement

I have one string array to hold some options and 470 string array to hold this option's values  I use a spinner to populate a options string array. I want to select an array from between 470 arrays according to selected option. For example if i select 2. option i want to print values2 array to screen. How can i do. I dont want to use 470 if then else blocks.

```
final  String[] options={"option0","option1","option2","option3"...};

final  String[] values0={"kjhk","kjhkhkhk","asfasd"};
final  String[] values1={"gvctc","ononnnın","njbsalna"};
final  String[] values2={"aasd","qwert","asadad"};
.
.
final  String[] values470{"ljlj","ljljl","opıuo"};

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,long id) {


}
```

Comment: This question is much too broad. Use a database. Google it. Then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: I search this since one weeks on everywhere but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Once again -- forget about arrays and hardcoding this. Use a database.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to setup your data by hand.
Here's a quick & dirty solution based on your provided information and data structure :

```
    Map<String,List<String>> optionToValueMap=new HashMap<>();
    List<String>values= new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("1");
    values.add("2");
    optionToValueMap.put("option0",values);
    // get values for 'option0'
    for (String value:optionToValueMap.get("option0")){

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is perfect solution but it can do what you want.

```
final  String[] options={"option0","option1","option2","option3"...};
final  String[] values0={"kjhk","kjhkhkhk","asfasd"};
final  String[] values1={"gvctc","ononnnın","njbsalna"};
final  String[] values2={"aasd","qwert","asadad"};
//form an two dimensional array
final String[][] values={values0,values1,values2};
```

OnSpinner Clickevent

```
  spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,long id) {

  //here you get an particular array.
   String[] array=values[position];
```

}